# Popover modal (quick view) for selected item in array list - Twig, Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Please i have array list of product that displays in twig. I will like to display a popover modal view(quick view) for each product. for example when i click on quick view for item 1, i want the information for item 1 to display on the modal popover view. Thanks

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}


<header class="page-heading">
    <div class="container">

        <h2>Collection</h2>
    </div>

</header>

<section class="new-arrivals">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="row">

                {% for entry in product %}


                    <div class="col-sm-4 item">
                        <div class="item-image">
                            <img src="{{ asset('product/'~ entry.imageName )  }}" alt="shirt">

                            <div class="hover-overlay">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                                    <li><a class="expand" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_view"><i class="icon-expand"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="item-info">
                            <h5>{{ entry.name }}</h5>
                            <ul class="price list-unstyled list-inline">
                                <li class="current">{{ entry.price  }}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="product_view">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                                    <h3 class="modal-title">{{ entry.name }}</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 product_img">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('product/'~ entry.imageName )  }}" class="img-responsive">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 product_content">
                                            <h4>Product Id: <span>51526</span></h4>
                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                                (10 reviews)
                                            </div>
                                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                                            <h3 class="cost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> 75.00 <small class="pre-cost"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span> 60.00</small></h3>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="select">
                                                        <option value="" selected="">Color</option>
                                                        <option value="black">Black</option>
                                                        <option value="white">White</option>
                                                        <option value="gold">Gold</option>
                                                        <option value="rose gold">Rose Gold</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="select">
                                                        <option value="">Capacity</option>
                                                        <option value="">16GB</option>
                                                        <option value="">32GB</option>
                                                        <option value="">64GB</option>
                                                        <option value="">128GB</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="select">
                                                        <option value="" selected="">QTY</option>
                                                        <option value="">1</option>
                                                        <option value="">2</option>
                                                        <option value="">3</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- end col -->
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="space-ten"></div>
                                            <div class="btn-ground">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add To Cart</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Add To Wishlist</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>






                {% endfor %}


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





{% endblock %}
```

the div class "div class="modal fade" id="product_view""is the one that serves the popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you modal divs have the same id attribute, and you data-target references it, so I guess only the first popup would open.
Just add a key to that id and data-target attributes

```
id="product_view_{{loop.index}}"
```